# PHP array_key_exists() and SPL ArrayAccess interface: not compatible?

Tags: php, arrays, spl

I wrote a simple collection class so that I can store my arrays in objects:

```
class App_Collection implements ArrayAccess, IteratorAggregate, Countable
{
    public $data = array();

    public function count()
    {
        return count($this->data);
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset)
    {         
        return (isset($this->data[$offset]));
    }   

    public function offsetGet($offset)
    {  
        if ($this->offsetExists($offset))
        {
            return $this->data[$offset];
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value)
    {         
        if ($offset)
        {
            $this->data[$offset] = $value;
        }  
        else
        {
            $this->data[] = $value; 
        }
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset)
    {
        unset($this->data[$offset]);
    }

    public function getIterator()
    {
        return new ArrayIterator($this->data);
    }
}
```

**Problem:** when calling array_key_exists() on this object, it always returns "false" as it seems this function is not being handled by the SPL. Is there any way around this?

**Proof of concept:**

```
$collection = new App_Collection();
$collection['foo'] = 'bar';
// EXPECTED return value: bool(true) 
// REAL return value: bool(false) 
var_dump(array_key_exists('foo', $collection));
```

Comment: array_key_exists does not work with *ArrayAccess* but it does w/ *ArrayObject*, see: https://3v4l.org/gYeCM

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a known issue which *might* be addressed in PHP6. Until then, use `isset()` or `ArrayAccess::offsetExists()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; could you provide a reference with that?

Comment: I don't believe this is written anywhere in the manual, because it wasn't a design choice. It was a design oversight, a bug I might say. There are many inconsistencies in the PHP language. I've proposed this functionality on the PHP internals mailing list, and people agreed with me, but it will going to be a long time until it will get implemented. I don't know C unfortunately.

Comment: Here's a link to that discussion: http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=122483924802616&w=2

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Diving intro SPL makes me realize more and more how inconsistent the language is. For now, I'll just isset().

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but is there any update around this, any workarounds available? I am trying to refactor in an application where switching to isset is not an option.

Stuff like this makes one get angry at php, not which order array functions take parameters..

Comment: @cubsink seems to be working as desired in PHP 5.4.24.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan and as desired means.. calling offsetExists?

Comment: @cubsink I meant this: https://gist.github.com/igstan/e7d3458260f67895dacb Are you dealing with a different issue?

Comment: I think this is the same issue. I have a class where I have implemented the ArrayAccess (and extending ArrayObject) but when calling array_key_exists('foo', $myobj) it always returns false. I just thought it would call offsetExists on my class.

Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for the super quick answers :)

Comment: @cubsink you're right, it doesn't call `offsetExists`. My gist looks like it's working because casting an `ArrayObject` to an array constructs the expected array, and `array_key_exists` seems to perform an internal cast.

Maybe you can redefine `array_key_exists` in another namespace? https://gist.github.com/igstan/87154e85ffc5f2fe30e3

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan woah, never thought of that as a possibility. Now I just have to talk over my tech lead that we should pursue this option instead of the ugly hack I did earlier today to solve this.

Comment: It's worth noting that `isset` and `array_key_exists` behave differently: `isset` will return `false` if it encounters a `null` (but existing) value, while `array_key_exists` will return `true`.  In order to account for this and maintain compatibility with `isset`, you would need to create an additional method to check whether a key exists, since `offsetExists` is (perhaps erroneously) used by `isset`.  In theory, `isset` should call `offsetGet` if `offsetExists` returns `true`, but, in practice, I believe this does not happen as of PHP 5.5.

Comment: php 7.2.0alpha2 behaves the same way

Comment: Aand, 10 years later since the question and 2 years since the last comment, this thing is still claiming hours of debugging off the unsavvy. I know this comment is slightly off-key, I'll take the blame for it.

Comment: Still a problem, it seems. :(